# Kind of Self-Referencing Problem with EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an Article Entity with some Article-Parts Entities as child properties, which in turn reference other Article Entities:

[image]

My Problem is, that on Saving Ef Core overwrites my "PartArticle" property with the parent-article.
So in my UI I have configured Article A consists of 10x Article B and 5x Article C,
which seems to be fine until the last breakpoint before SaveChangesAsync().

After saving the data reads "Article A consists of 10x Article A and 5x Article A"

I think I could introduce another HelperClass, but is there some easier way with configuring relations properly?
Currently I have:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ArticlePart>().HasOne(p => p.PartArticle).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
 modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().HasMany(a => a.ArticleParts).WithOne(a => a.PartArticle);
```

Any help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Maybe you should show us how you implemented "*ArticleA consists of 10x ArticleB and 5x ArticleC*"?

Comment: [Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by introducing explicit Foreign-Keys:

```
public class ArticlePart
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ArticleCount { get; set; }

    public int PartArticleId { get; set; }
    public int ParentArticleId { get; set; }

    public Article? PartArticle { get; set; }
    public Article? ParentArticle { get; set; }
 
}
```

And my Configuration:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ArticlePart>().HasOne(p => p.PartArticle).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.PartArticleId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        
 modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().HasMany(a => a.ArticleParts).WithOne(a => a.ParentArticle).HasForeignKey(a => a.ParentArticleId);
```